# Why don't the Scavengers speak properly?

Tags: the-walking-dead

The Scavengers appear first in S7. At first I thought it was only their enigmatic leader who spoke a weird dialect but it seems they all do.

The Walkers have only been around for a few years at this point so society hasn't devolved. Do we know (or will we) where their odd language and behaviour come from?

Comment: They also speak very little. SPOILER: After they're all killed, the main one starts talking normal again. My theory is that it was an in-group thing.

Comment: My guess is it was due to some sort of PTSD because of the societal collapse.